# Get rendered source code from web components site?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, polymer, web-component

I just tried something rather trivial: get the source code of a web page (by saving it) and count how often a certain phrase occurs in the code.

Turns out, it doesn't work if that page uses [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org) / web components. Is this a browser bug?

Try the following: Go to http://www.google.com/design/icons/ and try to find `star_half` in the code (the last icon on the page). If you inspect the element inside of Chrome or Firefox, it will lead you to

```
<i class="md-icon dp48">star_half</i>
```

but this won't be in the source if you copy the root node or save the html to disk.

Is there a way to get the entire code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for this behavior is probably how *source viewing*( and *source saving* as well?) works for browser and because [shadow roots](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) are attached to web components on the client side.

When you press ctrl-u on a web page, browser essentially does a network call again on the same url to fetch a copy of what **server** returned when you hit that url.

In this case, when [this](http://www.google.com/design/icons/) page renders, browser identifies the component `icons-layout` and then executes code to attach a [shadow-root](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) to this node. All of this happens when your page reaches the client(browser).

When you are trying to save this page, you are saving *what server returned* not current state of the page. You'll see same behavior if you fire up chrome console and try to save an `icons-layout` node.

> Is there a way to get the entire code?

I don't know how to do it from browser but phantomjs provides a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720218/get-a-browser-rendered-htmljavascript) to save client side rendered html.