# How to save a single webpage with a Linux server

Tags: html, linux, shell, command-line

I'm trying to save data descriptions from the open data site with a Linux server via SSH:

https://dandelion.eu/datagems/SpazioDati/milano-grid/resource/

https://dandelion.eu/datagems/SpazioDati/milano-grid/description/

I've read the question ([What's the best way to save a complete webpage on a linux server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769433/whats-the-best-way-to-save-a-complete-webpage-on-a-linux-server)) and tried `wget -l 1 https://dandelion.eu/datagems/SpazioDati/milano-grid/description/` and `wget -m https://dandelion.eu/datagems/SpazioDati/milano-grid/description/`. Neither of them worked. All I can get is an index.html. I want to have the files that I can get using IE/Firefox's 'Save Page' function 'Web page, complete' on a PC. There should be an html file and a folder containing all the stuff like images and such.

Is this possible on a Linux server via SSH? Thanks!

**Update**

This is what I want (I 'Save page' https://dandelion.eu/datagems/SpazioDati/milano-grid/description/ with Firefox):

```
|---Milano Grid description _ dandelion_files
| |---a
| |---css_all.css
| |---css.css
| |---dc.js
| |---fbk.jpg
| |---jquery_002.js
| |---jquery.js
| |---js_all.js
| |---js_sitebase.js
| |---Milano_GRID_4326.png
| |---milano-grid-img2.jpg
| |---mixpanel-2.js
| |---odi.png
| |---sbi.css
| |---spaziodati_black.png
| |---spaziodati_white.png
| |---telecom.png
|---Milano Grid description _ dandelion.htm
```

This is what I get with `wget -p -k https://dandelion.eu/datagems/SpazioDati/milano-grid/description/`:

```
|---dandelion.eu
| |---datagems
| | |---SpazioDati
| | | |---milano-grid
| | | | |---resource
| | | | | |---index.html
| |---jsi18n
| | |---index.html
| |---robots.txt
```

Comment: Can you describe what about wget is not working? Never mind, looks like you also want the assets have you tried -kp?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348289/download-a-working-local-copy-of-a-webpage

Comment: The only file I can get is an index.html (8kb). I downloaded it via sftp and opened it on my PC. The file has nothing compared with the real webpage.

Comment: I tried `wget -p -k https://dandelion.eu/datagems/SpazioDati/milano-grid/resource/` and it's not working. Sure I got a folder of stuff but that's not what I want. I'd like to get the same files that I can get using IE/Firefox's 'Save page' function. I'll appreciate it a lot if you can try the command above and compare the differences.

Comment: Im on a phone unfortunately, if i get a minute when i get to a pc (prob an hour or more) ill let you know, but it wont be over ssh

Comment: Also can you post an exmple of the difference in files for sanities sake?

Comment: Updated at the end of my question, thanks!